# NetworkManager will not allow me to select WPA

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, wpa

I have a fresh install of Crunchbang (basically Ubuntu with Openbox instead of Gnome). In any case, I can't connect to my WPA network - when I click on it in the nm-applet and it asks me to authenticate my only options are:

- WEP 10/128-bit key
- WEP 128-bit Passphrase
- LEAP
- Dynamic WEP (802.1x)

wpa_supplicant is indeed installed, yet WPA does not get listed... any ideas?

Comment: What wifi card do you have? Is the proper driver installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much heartache and inconvenience, I figured out the problem. This is on an -old- laptop. It turns out the card is not compatible. Such is life, sometimes...